# Any tips on figuring out programming in Unreal Engine (without focusing mainly on blueprints, or at least a fairly even mix of the two?)

Tags: c++, unreal-4

So for the past few months I've been attempting to learn Unreal Engine. Most tutorials feature blueprints which I guess makes sense as it's new and simple and their solution to artists trying to make games. However, when learning to code or program anything, I've always valued actually understanding what I'm typing in. It makes it easy to remember, especially when it's not a habit like say, typing in `int main()`
before starting your C++ code.
When I need to write code spontaneously, I find it valuable to understand what I'm typing in.

However, UE4's usage of C++ is almost as if you're learning a new derived language, which is what was once done by users of Unreal Engine. Outrageously though, I've found no source which explains the vast amount of macro's and jargon used when programming games in UE4. Thing's such as `GENERATED_UCLASS_BODY()` or `void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* InputComponent) override;`
Perhaps the terms void, class, and override have been mentioned in typical C++, but the Unreal API is a mystery, and I've found no place where I can know what any of this actually means, or more importantly -in my view of course-, why I'm connecting them the way I'm told too. It's somewhat obvious that all these are related, but it's harder to uncover how they're to be formatted and linked together. Does anyone know a way I can get a better understanding of the library of macros and terms Epic has taken no time to explain?

Comment: Were the C++ tutorials of no use? - https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Tutorials/index.html | or the source code? - https://www.unrealengine.com/ue4-on-github

Comment: "add the following code to AMyPawn::AMyPawn:" < it's lines like this that I hope to avoid, because they're literally doing nothing but getting you into the habit of typing in those words, without explaining why you're doing so.

Comment: I've come to the same conclusion as OP, and ended up giving up. It takes so long to compile any code changes, and find out you messed up some strange UE4 syntax and get a compile error. Took me weeks to implement something that would take 2 hours in Unity's C#. I'll be sticking to Blueprints as much as I can.

Comment: I've had similar experiences where I've just given up on using C++ for certain aspects and going down the blueprint way. Unfortunately there are still tings Blueprints alone can't handle, and even for blueprints, I haven't found a source that teaches it in any other way than rote memorization and habit.